# How to have html in Text attribute of asp Button

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to include an `<i>` for the Text attribute for an asp button but it's just rendering the html as text...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="modify" ToolTip="Modify" CssClass="btn btn-mini" OnClick="modify_Onclick" Text='<i class="icon-edit"></i>' />
```

I've got to be over thinking this...

**EDIT:** 
I'm using the twitter bootstrap framework. That's why the `<i>` tag. Here's an example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: Why do you have an italics tag with a class of icon-edit in the text value of a button in the first place? Are you sure you're not looking for an asp:ImageButton? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx

Comment: Maybe a little more clarifying.  Are you wanting the text to be italicized or are you trying to get the html code to literally show up as the button text?

Comment: Don't really think you are overthinking this, I don't think it's possible to put HTML into the text of the asp:Button as it treats this as a literal.  What is it your are trying to accomplish?  I think you need a differnt approach.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What I ended up doing was going with an html button, `runat=server` and putting the `<i>` inside of that.

```
<button runat="server" id="modify" class="btn btn-mini" title="Modify" onserverclick="modify_Onclick">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: but how to trigger the server-side event, the onclick of such button doesn't do it!! The only way I see to do so is to put a hidden control and trigger it using javascript or jquery, is that true or is there a better way to do it??

Comment: M009 use `onserverclick="function_name"`

Comment: don't use this way, it makes problems while using Jquery functions

Comment: Don't you just love incomplete answers; +1 Zorgarath, and what is the signature of the on click function name?

Answer (score 32):

You can use `<asp:LinkButton`. Bootstrap renders anchor tags (asp:LinkButton) like input type submit buttons (asp:Button).

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="modify" ToolTip="Modify" CssClass="btn btn-mini" OnClick="modify_Onclick" Text='<i class="icon-edit"></i>' />
```

Comment: Link Button is different from asp button. Link button would raise a postback but will not submit the form. So say if you have some HTML5 validations, they will not work natively with Link Button.

Comment: I opted for the approach in the answer from @bflemi3 - but when triggering the .click() mtehod, the HTML5 error code runs - but continues to issue the postback without waiting for the HTML5 error hander.

Answer (score 7):

You would do it like this

```
    <button runat="server" id="btnRun" onserverclick="functionName" class="btn btn-mini" title="Search">
    <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search
    </button>
```

Take a look at this example (however if you are using sitefinity CMS this won't work)
[Font awesome inside asp button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064005/font-awesome-inside-asp-button)

Answer (score 7):

You can exploit the `<label>` tag's `for` attribute.
Basically any click on `<label>` will also fire the click event of a html element with an id same as `<label>`'s `for` attribute

For example:

```
<label for="modify"><i class="icon-edit"></i></label>
<asp:Button style="display:none;" runat="server" ID="modify" ToolTip="Modify" CssClass="btn btn-mini" OnClick="modify_Onclick" Text='' />
```

clicking the `<label>` element here(which clicks the `<i>` element too), will fire the `<asp:button>`'s click event.

Comment: I found this helpful enough to give a vote up - even it does not solve the problem at all

Comment: This was perfect for me when using Zurb Foundation as its button classes can be applied to a label for same display as if it were an actual button.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you change your button to an:

```
<asp:LinkButton />
```

it works perfectly fine within the text attribute. I don't believe there will be any loss in functionality.

Comment: As Cem said in their answer approx. three years ago.

Comment: @PaulZahra I prefer my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If it renders as a `<input type="submit">` you cannot display HTML as the label. It will render as a literal string.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkNuX/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something where you render an html link that has the "i" tag inside of it (if you look at the source of the link you provided, that's what they do) and then make it postback on click using the ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference() to get a reference to the postback script.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx

So for example:

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="javascript:<% ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference()%>"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh</a>
```

This is just out of my head, so you might need to tweak it a bit.  You could then just roll this into your own custom asp.net control.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to render html inside a button on the client side, I didn't want it to be using `runat="server"` so what I did was using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button_<%= this.id %>').innerHtml = '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>';
```