# Font awesome inside asp button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

This is my asp:button code which is not rendering font awesome's icon but instead shows the HTML as it is:

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRun" Text="<i class='icon-camera-retro'></i> Search" ValidationGroup="edt" OnClick="btnRun_Click"  CssClass="greenButton"/>
```

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the rendered HTML?  Can you see where the value of `Text` is placed?

Comment: yes, it is placed inside value attribute of input type text.

Comment: Correct, and therefore HTML is not going to be parsed **within** that attribute

Comment: @freefaller: Please read Ryan's answer.

Comment: OK, I have read it - and I can't see anything that would make me change my comments.  I can't see him trying to put HTML into an attribute

Comment: Right. I meant you should read how to solve this issue. I didn't expect an obvious comment of "look HTML rendered". I already knew that and hence "shows the HTML as it is" in my question. My question was how to solve the issue and hence "Any idea how can I solve this issue?" in my question at the end. Hope you get the idea about the question and it's solution.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can't with the default asp.net button you will need to use a HTML button and give it runat=server attribute:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnRun" class="btn btn-mini" title="Search">
    <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search
</button>
```

So use code behind with this you add:

```
onserverclick="functionName"
```

To the button, then in your C# do:

```
protected void functionName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World!!!");
}
```

So final button looks like:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnRun" onserverclick="functionName" class="btn btn-mini" title="Search">
    <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search
</button>
```

Comment: Great but that brings in bigger problems. How do I now handle server side click event of button? Write manual __doPostBack?

Comment: @Jack, You can do with existing button itself. I added display:none to hide and i click when the user click button using javascript. Check my answer

Comment: If you need just an icon without text, Rafe's solution (below) is easier to handle because it does not require to change any code in code behind. Otherwise I would recommend to use a LinkButton and only if this is not an option, I would use Ryan's solution.

Answer (score 43):

You can use a LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRun" Text="<i class='icon-camera-retro'></i> Search" 
                ValidationGroup="edt" OnClick="btnRun_Click" CssClass="greenButton" />
```

They do support html in the text field.

Comment: I think I prefer to have the HTML outside of the properties: `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRun" ValidationGroup="edt" OnClick="btnRun_Click" CssClass="greenButton"><i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search</asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: Of course you can do that with a asp:LinkButton. But my question is about an asp:Button.

Comment: @Tillito and the marked answer is _not_ an Asp.NET button.

Comment: Youre the real mvp

Answer (score 17):

You can do it, jut not purely with CSS. You just need to set the Text property on the button to the unicode value of the fontawesome character and give the button the 'fa' css class so it takes up the fontawesome font.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="\xF135" CssClass="fa" />
```

I made this helper library that provides all the icon codes strongly-typed if that turns your crank:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="<%# FontAwesome.Icons.Rocket %>" CssClass="fa" />
```

Nuget: Install-Package FontAwesome-ASP.NET

Source: https://github.com/kemmis/FontAwesome-ASP.NET

Comment: Tried this approach. The button just rendered the text "\xF135" instead of the icon. I had to use code &#xf002; from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: Mind that when you use also text next to the icon it will also be of the awesome font - which looks ugly. So this approach is the best when you have just an icon to display.

Comment: @Tillito I was able to get around this over here by wrapping the control sequences in inner tags same as the FA guidelines: <button runat="server" id="btnZip" class="Button" title="Download Zip">&nbsp;
                <i class="fa">&#xf1c6;</i>&nbsp;Download</button>

Comment: @mjw: you are right. See Ryan McDonough's answer which I marked as the solution.

Comment: This should be the answer. It's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 11):

Use LinkButton

```html
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRun" ValidationGroup="edt" OnClick="btnRun_Click" CssClass="greenButton" > <i class='icon-camera-retro'></i> Search </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: The problem is that there are several reasons why one might not be able to use a link button (since that converts to a link instead of actually being a button) which can break what the someone is trying to accomplish.  Certain bootstrap behaviors are broken by trying to use a link button instead of an asp:Button

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this solution -

```
<span  style="position:relative;">
    <i class="fa fa-hand-o-down"></i>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCatMoveDown" CssClass="movedown" CausesValidation="false" Text="" CommandName="categorymovedown" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SomeId")%>' runat="server"></asp:Button>
</span>

<style>
    .movedown {
        position:absolute;
        opacity:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the others answers changes asp:button by other one, I show you if you want use asp:button, EASY :)

```css
/*CSS*/
/*Colors depends what btn you use, in this case i´m using btn-default*/

.btn_asp_icon{
    border: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover > .btn_asp_icon{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="btn btn-default">

<i class="fa fa-search fa-fw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<asp:Button cssClass="btn_asp_icon" runat="server" text="Consultar"/>   

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it on Nuget!

Install-Package FontAwesome-ASP.NET
Usage

FontAwesome Icons In Webforms Buttons

You can use FontAwesome icons inside asp.net webforms button controls. Simply databind to the icon of your choice from the FontAwesome.Icons class' static properties. Then either call DataBind() on your button or DataBind() on your parent control or page.

```html
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="<%# FontAwesome.Icons.Rocket %>" CssClass="fa" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your **Load form** method:

`btn_Test.Text = "Hello " + FontAwesome.Icons.LongArrowRight;`

And the **CssClass** button:

`CssClass="fa"`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me for v5.15

I had to add the following files to a folder named fonts under wwwroot

1. FontAwesome.otf
2. fontawesome-webfront.eot
3. fontawesome-webfront.svg
4. fontawesome-webfront.ttf
5. fontawesome-webfront.woff
6. fontawesome-webfront.woff2

```html
<div>
    <a asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="CSHTMLFILE"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-arrow-left "></i> Go Back to Previous Page</a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function redirectToButton(buttonId) {
  document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
}
```

```css
.btnHidden {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0rem;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-primary" onclick="redirectToButton('<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>')">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btnHidden" ID="btnSearch" Font-Bold="true" Text="Search" />
</div>
```