# The best way to use Font Awesome cheat sheet in Asp:Button

Tags: css, asp.net, font-awesome

As it is not possible to use the font awesome in the Asp:Button. I came across to use the Font Awesome cheat sheet from the comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629250/2923670)  as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn fa" Text="&#xf044;">
</asp:Button>
```

But now, `Text="&#xf044;"` looks so awkward. Is there some way to use constants, so use like this, `Text="edit"` and `edit` has the value `&#xf044;`

Answer (score 0):

One possible option:

Declare a constant variable to store the text -

```
protected const string AWESOME_EDIT = "&#xf044;";
```

Bind to it in the tag -

```
<asp:Button ID="btEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn fa" Text='<%# AWESOME_EDIT %>'></asp:Button>
```

Unfortunately, then you have to explicitly databind the page (or particular item) -

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
    //or, btEdit.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: why can't I use `Page.DataBind();`

Comment: @Kami you can do that too -  updated answer to show both options