# Why is my CSS not being applied to <asp:Linkbutton> having classCss property? Although it gets applied on a simple HTML button tag

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble in applying my external CSS on asp:LinkButton tag. When Css is applied on simple button tag it works fine in case of asp:LinkButton tag its not working. Need Help!

[image]

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="wrapper"> <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type='submit' name='search' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" id="LinkButton1" CssClass="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Is `cssClass` a correct attribute?

Comment: Yes. well I am beginner. # asp.net

Comment: What is the output of <asp:LinkButton> in the browser?

Comment: Simple search icon without grey background as shown in above image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the CSS change isn't reflecting in your asp:LinkButton because an asp:LinkButton generates a hyperlink `<a>...</a>` while in the other span element above you are using a button `<button></button>` which are not equivalent. Try using something like `<asp:Button ...>` instead of a `<asp:LinkButton ...>` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Initially, I tried using <button></button> but it gives error "the element ' i ' cannot be nested within element button."

Comment: In that case you may just use a normal HTML <button> along with a runat="server". It would work in a similar manner. Please see this for a more detailed discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064005/font-awesome-inside-asp-button?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

The second solution in the linked post seems do-able as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. problem resolved but I have another confusion yet. How can I add functionality i.e. connection to database/ c# function call on that html button. any referral link. I tried finding but could get any relevant to my problem

Comment: Please see the attached link on how to manage database connectivity:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038536/Day-Database-Connectivity-ASP-NET-Csharp-with-SQL
Its the bare minimum you need to know if you're starting out.

However, I would strongly recommend you to follow a 3-tier architecture for better software design. Something like this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/71/3-tier-architecture-in-aspnet-with-csharp

P.S Don't forget to upvote. Thanks!